# Want to generate unique key of 15 chars in java

Tags: java, unique

I want to generate unique of 15 chars in java. Requests are coming to multiple servers and it should support 3-4 years of timeframe.
Also, we can consider 15 tps max.

Please point me into right direction.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: ***Please point me into right direction.***... yes, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using UUID. It has much higher length than you specified, but it has a very low (like really low) probability to give you the same values in different runs. It is pretty commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state your security requirements.  For a non-secure solution use 15 digit base 36 numbers.  The digits are A..Z, 0..9 and increment the numbers in the usual way.  It may be easier to use ordinary increment of a variable and convert to base 36 at the end.

For a secure solution, encrypt the underlying number and convert the encrypted number to base 36.  As long as the inputs are unique: 1, 2, 3 ... K, L, M, ... 1H2J, 1H2K, 1H2L ... then the encrypted outputs will be unique.

You may want to omit potentially confusing letters like I, O and Z (confused with 1, 0 and 2) and reduce to base 33 output.

15 digits in base 36 gives 2.18e42 unique numbers, which should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to generate unique ID ...

I think you must consider the [UUIDs (Universal Unique IDs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

The standard Java libraries include [many options to generate UUIDs](http://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid). For instance, you can use the [java.util.UUID](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-uuid-guid-in-java/) introduced in Java 1.5. In addition, You can also use other opensource libraries such as [Java UUID Generator](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator) of the [UUID library](http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/). Johan Bukard [compares some of them](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/Java-UUID-generators-compared.html).

> I want to generate unique of 15 chars in java

15 chars ?

Usually, UUIDs are represented by 32 hexadecimal (base 16) digits. If you need an ID with only 15 chars you may check the source code of the JDK or the JUG and create your own code.

Usually an UUID combines information from the device (such as the Apple UUID or the MAC address of a network interface) with a timestamp.